# Modal dialog box does not communicate with main HTA window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, hta

I have a javascript in an HTA which looks like this:

```
var result = null;
window.showModalDialog("dialog.hta", window, "dialogHeight:300px; dialogWidth:300px");
alert(result);
```

dialog.hta:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>Dialog box</title>
     <meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="yes"/>
</head>
<body style="background:#F0F0F0">
     <select id="colors">
          <option selected>Red</option>
          <option>Blue</option>
          <option>Green</option>
          <option>Yellow</option>
     </select><br/>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function ok(){
               window.dialogArguments.result = colors.getElementsByTagName("option")[colors.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
               window.close();
          }
     </script>
     <button onclick="ok()">OK</button>
     <button onclick="window.close()">Cancel</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I press OK the `alert(result)` in the main HTA window always says null, even when I click on the OK button in the modal dialog box.
How can I do so that it says which option the user selects in the list when the OK button is pressed and null when the cancel button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how modal dialog works:

In the main app:

```
// Call a dialog, and store the returned value to a variable
var result = showModalDialog(path, argument, options);
```

On dialog close:

```
// Set the returnValue
var elem = document.getElementById("colors");
window.returnValue = elem[elem.selectedIndex].text;
top.close();
```

After setting the `returnValue` *in*  the dialog, you can read it from `result` after the dialog has been closed.

`option` elements didn't have `innerHTML` in old IEs, hence you've to use `text` property instead. You can also add a `value` attribute to the `select` element, and then create a return value in a simple way:

```
window.returnValue = document.getElementById('colors').value;
```